# Angular 2 index.html missing?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm supposed to work on an Angular 2 project. I don't have much experience with it, but I used Angular 1.x before.

The project is using Angular 2 and Webpack. After I built the project I can only see the directory list in the browser and it is clearly missing the index.html file. All angular 2 projects I've seen, including tutorial project had an index.html file set up there from the beginning. I haven't been able to find anyone else with this problem. There is an index.ts file in root/ClientSource/app/

I mainly wanted to find out whether there's any specific reason this file is missing and if adding it to the project should be something I would normally do after building the project or is there a chance the previous developer forgot to add it?

I'm attaching a screenshot from the root directory of the project and a part of package.json (hopefully it'll be useful).

PS. I'm only supposed to style the website and make it interactive, so once the project is up and running I'm good.

Thank you!

[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o39o.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41dkJ.png)

Comment: Are you using any starter project or you have create it from scratch.

Comment: does `npm start` work? as far as i can see, it should start a webserver that you can access via http instead of file:// access

Comment: @JijoCleetus I didn't create this project, I received it from another person. I'm not sure whether he used a starter project.

Comment: @MaxFichtelmann good quesiton! I get redirected to localhost:3000 and see "Cannot GET /" message

Comment: Nothing inside the wwwroot?

Comment: @Sakuto this is what's inside of wwwroot https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwlQx.png

Comment: There should be an index.html file. May be missing in your repo.